# How do you store user input in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a bot setup and I'd like to add a function that converts USD to CAD using a prefixed command like !tocad $USD that will take the number entered ($USD) and convert it to CAD. The conversion part isn't an issue, but being new to JS and Discord.js I'm struggling to figure out how to store that first argument in a variable so I can use it to do the calculation.

```
case 'tocad':
            let(args[1] === //How do I store this integer?//){ 
                
                message.channel.send(userInteger * 1.31); //does math
            }
            else{
                message.channel.send('That's not a valid amount.' ) //if input isn't in integer format
            }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `args` with [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which will split a string into an array of the results.

```js
// splitting the message by every space will return an array of every word
// using `Array.prototype.slice()`, we can remove the first element in the array (the command)
// now all that's left is every variable after
const args = message.content.split(/ +/);
```

---

Here's a code snippet example:

```js
const message = '!tocad 30.79';
const args = message.split(/ +/).slice(1);

console.log(args); // array of every word in the message
console.log(args[0]); // first element of the array; first word of the string
```

---

Lastly, this variable will be stored as a `String`, so make sure to convert it to a number before multiplying it using the `+` operator.

```js
if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please provide a number');

if (Number.isNaN(+args[0])) // if args[0] is not a number
   return message.channel.send('That is not a number');

message.channel.send(+args[0] * 1.31);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `args` is obtained from `split`ing a string, `args[1]` will be a string (or `undefined`), not an integer/number.

To assign, the variable name goes on the left and the value on the right. Something like this:

```js
const userInteger = parseInt(args[1])
```